# How can I turn off my TV without turning off my PS3?

Tags: ps3, monitor

I've got it set up so the PS3 and TV communicate via HDMI and turning one or the other on/off turns them both on/off.

If I'm in the middle of a video game (and paused) I can turn off the TV without the console shutting down. However, if I'm just at the downloads management screen I can't.

Is there a way to temporarily disable the HDMI communication? I'd rather not have to go into the settings for something so simple, but that's probably easier than then RL hack I've been using of pulling the HDMI cable out while I power off the TV.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you've done this ... I have an HDMI cable connecting my PS3 and TV and they have always turned off separately.

Comment: @Dave: System Settings > Control for HDMI.  
It's not really a huge deal, but it would be nice if there was some sort of key press (Like hold O while turning off the TV) to temporarily disable this.

Comment: ah, interesting. Never thought about that - I run Folding@home on mine when I'm not using it, so I've never had an occasion when I wanted to turn them both off at once.

Comment: I do F@H during the winter, but it's too hot in the summer time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [online user guide](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/ctrlhdmi.html), there is an apparent way to circumvent the PS3's shutdown:

> Even when [On] is selected, this
> feature (*HDMI Control*) may not be available in the
> following cases:
>
> - When using certain features of the PS3™ system, such as gameplay or video
>   playback.
> - **When the PS3™ system is not selected as the input source for the TV.**

So it would seem that changing the TV's input before shutting it down should leave your Playstation running.

Comment: I would be interested in knowing if this works :D Would test but my PS3 is in box due to moving recently :S

Comment: It does work. Still not ideal, but I think this is the best option so I'ma mark this answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your TV/AV has a system inbuilt where, if an HDMI device is attached, it will turn this on automatically and vice-versa. You should be able to change this within the TV/AV's menu. Also try changing the source so the PlayStation is assigned something other than DVD.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my LG 55" LCD TV as it had the Simplink option turned on. Turn it off and the PS3 won't turn off when turning off the TV.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a LG or Samsung TV. LG TVs use Simplink, and Samusung uses Anynet. That allows you to control the HDMI connected devices using your TV remote.

So then go to Simplink settings in Setting - > Green button, and turn off to disable the feature.

It's similar for Samsung's Anynet.

But if you still want to use the feature and turn off your TV while your PS3 is downloading or charging its accessories, then you can turn off your TV display in powersaving settings.