# Why does my Xbox 360 reset when I change the input on my TV, unplug the HDMI cable, or turn the TV off?

Tags: xbox-360

I use my TV for my computer and Xbox. Today I was downloading the expansion for Battlefield 3. It's a 2gb download so I decided to switch and surf around. What I didn't notice is that as soon as I change input type or pull out the HDMI of my Xbox (just the HDMI) it auto resets. So when I pull it back in, my Xbox automatically starts up again. And it didn't download the whole time I was being on my computer, even though it is turned on.

Is this something normal or is this an option for safety that can be disabled?

Comment: By switch, do I understand you're yanking out the HDMI cable, not switching the input on your TV by using the remote, or both?

Comment: When I pull out the HDMI aswell as switching the input on my TV.

Comment: Which model of 360 do you have?

Comment: the newer slim model

Comment: this is not really a gaming question

Comment: @JerryRox Questions about hardware (like this one) [are allowed here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware?sort=newest), if the people who can best answer them are likely to be gamers themselves.

Answer (score 9):

Do you have the other AV cable (the one that has Component and Optical outputs) plugged in as well?  [This guy](http://forums.penny-arcade.com/discussion/99675/xbox-360-hdmi-turns-off-wtv-solved) was having a similar problem to you, and it turned out that the Xbox was switching output modes:

> From what my understanding is, the Xbox automatically detects when you switch to and from HDMI . And if you have the AV cables hooked up also it switches to the next connected mode which is: Component. The problem is the Xbox requires a restart when it switches modes.

If it's not that, it might be a feature of your TV called [CEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Definition_Multimedia_Interface#CEC) that you can probably disable:

> Consumer Electronics Control (CEC) is a feature designed to allow the user to command and control two or more CEC-enabled boxes, that are connected through HDMI, by using only one of their remote controls (for example by controlling a television set, set-top box, and DVD player using only the remote control of the TV).

Each TV vendor calls this something different in their options, but the Wikipedia article I linked contains some popular brands and what they call their version of this feature:

> Trade names for CEC are Anynet+ (Samsung); Aquos Link (Sharp); BRAVIA Link and BRAVIA Sync (Sony); HDMI-CEC (Hitachi); E-link (AOC); Kuro Link (Pioneer); CE-Link and Regza Link (Toshiba); RIHD (Remote Interactive over HDMI) (Onkyo); RuncoLink (Runco International); SimpLink (LG); HDAVI Control, EZ-Sync, VIERA Link (Panasonic); EasyLink (Philips); and NetCommand for HDMI (Mitsubishi).

Just in case you can't figure out why it's turning off, there's an option in the Xbox 360 preferences where you can specify if you want the console to stay on and continue a download even if you power it off.  In situations where you just want it on so that you can grab a big item off of the Microsoft servers, you can just set up the preferences properly, and then it will finish downloading regardless of whether or not you turn it off after you start the download.

Possibly related:

[How can I turn off my TV without turning off my PS3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24096/how-can-i-turn-off-my-tv-without-turning-off-my-ps3)

Comment: wow i woulda just figured he got to close to the sensing on button and it just clicked off

Answer (score 2):

Doing some general research turned up some old posts about using component for audio in conjunction with HDMI that could cause this glitch as well unless you buy MS' proprietary cables ($40, not worth it IMO)

Essentially it's a "working as intended" but a piss-poor design.

Answer (score 1):

Are you also using turtle beaches with your Xbox? If so, it is due to the Xbox trying to recognize which output it should use to display the picture.

For example, if you unplug the turtle beach out of the component jack and change the channel and then change it back it should not happen that time because it is not trying to choose between two possible outputs. In addition, when you plug the turtle beaches back into the component section it will restart if it's on.

Answer (score 1):

> I have experienced the same problem in the past - you should not need to turn off the CEC function on your TV.

First, go to your XBox settings, followed by SYSTEM, then CONSOLE SETTINGS, then DISPLAY and finally DISPLAY RECOVERY. Now make sure that this set to ON. This should cure your problem.

I fount that turning this off actually fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

My Xbox does this also, but using component cables. Basically whenever the cables are disconnected the OS shuts down so that it can readjust to whatever format you plug the xbox back into.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem in the past - you should not need to turn off the CEC function on your TV.

First, go to your XBox settings, followed by SYSTEM, then CONSOLE SETTINGS, then DISPLAY and finally DISPLAY RECOVERY. Now make sure that this set to ON. This should cure your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem for me.

I was seeing this problem because I had connected headphones using the same method as Turtle Beach headsets. That is using HDMI for the TV and the component connector for Audio. The easy way to check whether the component cable is causing the issue is to remove and plug in the cable while the XBOX is switched on. If the XBOX resets when you insert the cable it's certainly causing the problem (at the very least it's one of the things causing the problem and will need resolving).

To stop this I have placed tape over some of the pins leaving only the audio pins free to make contact in the XBOX. Below is the easiest way for me to describe what pins to cover without using Pin diagrams etc.

Use a torch or a well lit room so that you can see where the pins are on the component cable. My XBOX 360 cable (and I assume they're all the same) had two pairs of pins on the top and bottom of the connector. Use tape to cover the pairs of connectors nearest the edge of the connector both on the top and on the bottom. This will leave you with four pins near the centre of the connector. One pair almost opposite the other pair.

When inserting the connector the XBOX should not reset and you will still have the audio you require.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same exact problem, yet my brothers xbox would never do it.. He could switch to different inputs at will. I quickly found the solution that was causing it. I use headphones that you have to plug a big black box into my xbox, he doesn't. I unplugged my headphones. problem solved. Can switch at will.. the same thing will happen if your xbox is on and you plug in your headphones, the xbox will restart to accommodate the new sound settings